# How to do ProductSum in Excel?

Tags: excel

How to evaluate the following expression with **one single formula** in Excel for all values of *m* and *n*?

[image]

For example, the following matrix should give 3240:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

The column sums are 12, 15, 18 respectively. The product is therefore 3240.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your matrix is in `A1:C3`, then the *array formula* would be:

```
=PRODUCT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A1:C3),ROW(A1:C3)^0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your matrix is in `A1:C3`, then

```
=PRODUCT(SUM(A1:A3),SUM(B1:B3),SUM(C1:C3))
```

should do what you want.

If you want `Y1`to be `m` (count of factors in product - columns in sheet) and `Z1` to be `n` (count of summands in sum - rows in sheet) and matrix starts in `A1`, then:

```
{=PRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1:INDEX(A:A,Z1),,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,Y1))-1)))}
```

Note, this is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and the press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets then appears automatically.

Comment: Can this formula be dynamic, i.e. work for all values of *m* and *n*?

Comment: How do you want to provide values `m` and `n`?

Comment: They can be provided in any two cells, say Y1 and Z1